# Find a marker in a leaflet markercluster group

Tags: angularjs, leaflet, markerclusterer

I want to find a marker by it's marker.title property in a leaflet markercluster group. I'm using the angular-leaflet directive (v 0.7.5) with angular (1.2.8). The marker data is provided by a service. Here is the code I'm using:

```
    $timeout(function(){    
      leafletData.getLayers().then(function(layers) {
          $scope.markerClusterGrp = layers.overlays.locations;
          var clusters = $scope.markerClusterGrp.getLayers();
          for (var i in clusters){
            if (marker.title == clusters[i].options.title) {
              childMarker = clusters[i];
              break;
            } 
         }
      });       
    },1000);
```

This code works. However after I apply a filter to $scope.markers, the list of options.titles returned by above function is different from the list of marker.titles that's in $scope.markers. I've created a jsfiddle to illustrate this behavior. Please look at the console.log statements to see it in action. I am not sure if this is a bug or some error in my code.

http://jsfiddle.net/mukhtyar/z2Ucr/

My end goal is to find the visible parent of the marker i'm interested in and highlight the parent cluster in a mouseover event. Any help in explaining this behavior or suggestions on a different way to approach this problem are much appreciated! Thank you.

Edit: I got around this by using the clusters latlng instead of title.

```
//Iterate through all the markers
for (var i in clusters){
  if ((marker.lat == clusters[i]._latlng.lat) &&
    (marker.lng == clusters[i]._latlng.lng)) {
    childMarker = clusters[i];
    break;
  }
}
```